# In Jmeter ,Header manager don't add the jwt authorization token for testing Spring boot Rest API's

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, web-api-testing, jwt

I have extracted the JWT token from the User login controller Rest API(taken endpoints from swagger) and my test plan looks like this

[image: test plan]

[image: TEstplan.]

As you can see in the images in login request it takes the header of Breakdown Configuration and it doesn't take authorization token value pass as a JSON object in Bearer ${token} although I have extracted it in JSON extractor and debug sampler shows it.

I have also used the once only controller but it doesn't solve the issue. Please help in the nested Header Manager and how to use it correctly. Even I have used Bean Shell processor under my GETALL Bd-config request and pass the command:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;

sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("token")));
```

But it doesnt solve the issue. Please guide. My jwt token expiration time is 1 hour

Comment: could you show the "Request Body"

Answer (score 0):

Your test configuration is wrong, JMeter's [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) therefore your `Extract token` post-processor is being sequentially applied to:

1. Login
2. Debug Sampler - (ka-boom, here the token gets replaced by blank value)
3. GetAll bd-config

The solution will be putting these `Extract id` and `Extract token` as the children of the `Login` request

[image]

This way the token and the id will be extracted from the `Login` and remain until next iteration not being overwritten by the Debug Sampler